# Resolve the vector reflection equation to normal vector n

Tags: linear-algebra, reflection

Reflecting a vector $k_1$ at a plane with normal vector $\hat{n}$ is described by:

$$ \hat{k}_2 = \hat{k}_1 - 2(\hat{k}_1 \cdot \hat{n})\hat{n}$$

With $k_2$ being the reflected vector. All three vectors are normalised and 3 dimensional.

**How can you resolve this equation to $\hat{n}$?**

In words:  "For which normal vector does a given $k_1$ result in a given $k_2$?"

Comment: Just subtract the image from the original vector and normalize.

Comment: you mean $\dfrac{k_1 - k_2}{|k_1 - k_2|}$ ? If so, could you please explain. in any case thanks.

Comment: Just look at the formula that you’ve got for orthogonal projection: $\hat k_1$ and $\hat k_2$ differ by a multiple of $\hat n$.